# Help with finding the directional derivative of a $f(x,y,z)=xy+xz+yz$ at a point and in the direction of a vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to find the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)=xy+xz+yz$ at $P(1,2,3)$ in the direction of $\overrightarrow{v}=\langle 2,1,-1 \rangle$

I think I started this incorrectly and would greatly appreciate any hints!

$$f(x,y,z)=xy+xz+yz$$

$$f_x=y+z$$

$$f_y=x+z$$

$$f_z=x+y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :-

If $f(x,y)$ is a function and $u$ is an unit vector then the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $u$ is $\nabla f.u$, where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$.

Comment: Is my $u$ the point $P$?

Comment: @inquisitor ...no...you need to find it in direction of $u$..so $u$ is the vector $\frac {(2,1,-1)}{\sqrt{6}}$. $P$ is the point at which you will find the gradient of $f$.

Comment: That depends on the definition of directional derivative that the OP is using. Many sources don’t require a unit vector.